# Can an Adobe Air portable app run on Windows 8 RT?

Tags: windows, air, portable-applications

Is it possible to run an Adobe Air standalone app (portable, it got packed with the captive runtime) on Windows 8 RT?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. AIR supports Windows 8 desktop mode **only**. There is zero support for the Metro side. As Windows 8 RT only has the desktop available for Office and Windows Explorer, AIR is not supported.

From the [Adobe roadmap for the Flash runtimes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html):

> Adobe AIR is available and supported for Windows 8 Desktop on x86-based computers. Adobe currently has no plans to support Adobe AIR for Windows 8 Modern UI applications or Windows Mobile.

They originally did plan to support it, but cancelled support shortly after Windows 8 launched (and caused quite the stir among the community, too). Additionally, Windows 8 RT is ARM-based, which is not supported either (x86-only).